# Creating a templating function that passes in a name for a class

Tags: java, class, templates, extend

Let's say I have a set of classes I want to extend because they have different properties i'll use in my callback function (to come):

```
class ExtendMe1 //
class ExtendMe2 //
```

And I wanted to write a new class that extended it programmatically. Is there a way of doing something like this:

```
ExtenderTemplate(
    <ExtendMe1>, // Class to extend
    <AClassToExtendWith>, // New class name that i'm extending for
    CallbackFunction() // A function that can be run locally inside our new class
);
```

let's say that the method ExtenderTemplate looked something like this:

```
void ExtenderTemplate( <Ext>, <NewClass> )
{
    CreateClass( <NewClass ).Extends( <Ext> ).Run( CallbackFunction );
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in Java?

The resulting class would programmatically be built but would look like this:

```
public class AClassToExtendWith extends ExtendMe1
{
    public AClassToExtendWith()
    {
        CallbackFunction();
    }
    public void CallbackFunction()
    {
        // accesses something that belongs to ExtendMe1
    }
}
```

**Context**

We have a set of ui controls that we have to extend with our own class, do some routine crap inside it, then actually do something to extend the ui control (hopefully can be done with the callback function). It would be really great if we could pack this into some template method where in the end you just have these 3 paramaters.. which ui control are you extending, what do you want the class to be called (so we can call within our view) and finally what you will change about the ui control (the callback function)

**Further clarification of how our team might use this function**

- So I want to extend a UI Control that someone else has made.. I know what its called..
- I need to call it somehow in my code so I need to give it a nice new name... I also need to do this because I want to write some more functionality to it.
- I want to modify the UI control so that it uses my functionality instead.

I might end up calling it with something like (this will have to be pseudo)

```
ExtenderTemplate( "NewUIControl", "UIControl_Table", {
    UiControlRender.text = "New stuff added by accessing the extended method";
});
```

Otherwise I would have to do this:

```
public class NewUIControl extends UIControl_Table
{
    public void FunctionThatIsRunByFrameworkAutomatically()
    {
         // Do routine stuff that accesses UIControl_Table and makes copies of this and that

         // MODIFY THIS AND THAT WITH THE NEW STUFF I WANT IN THE UICONTROL            

         // Do  more routine stuff that belongs that accesses UIControl_Table and makes copies of this and that but passes in my modified stuff instead of the typical stuff the UI COntrol outputs
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the question tagged as Java is the best sign that this is a **Java** question, no need to add in title **nor again** as first line of your question.

Comment: you can make your template class with generics

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? What are the extended classes are supposed to model and what is the callback function going to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think, a [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is what you are looking for. Some sample code from the Proxy documentation:

To create a proxy for some interface Foo:

```
 InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler(...);
 Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(
     Foo.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { Foo.class });
 Foo f = (Foo) proxyClass.
     getConstructor(new Class[] { InvocationHandler.class }).
     newInstance(new Object[] { handler });
```

or more simply:

```
  Foo f = (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Foo.class.getClassLoader(),
                                      new Class[] { Foo.class },
                                      handler);
```

**Update:**

I just saw, that the Proxy class only proxies Interfaces, but does not seem to be able to extend classes.